# TypeError: Undefined is not a function - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

I'm getting an error on a overview page I have made.
I created a pagination for a overview table.
The pagination is working, but when loading the page I'm getting an error:

> "TypeError: undefined is not a function".

I couldn't get this fixed, I'm relative new to AngularJS.
The error is occuring in the following made filter on the last return line:

AngularJS:

```
angular.module('app').filter('pagination', function(){
    return function(input, start)
    {
        start = +start;
        return input.slice(start);
    };
});
```

HTML:

```
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="question in questions | orderBy:order:reverse | filter:searchText | pagination: curPage * pageSize | limitTo: pageSize">
        <td>{{ question.text }}</td>
        <td>{{ question.times_asked }}x </td>
        <td>--%</td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn" ng-click="createModel(question.id)">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
            </button>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn" ng-click="createDeleteModel(question.id)">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
            </button>
        </td><td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>

<div class="pagination pagination-centered" ng-show="questions.length">
<ul class="pagination-controle pagination">
 <li>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="curPage == 0"
 ng-click="curPage=curPage-1"> &lt; Vorige pagina</button>
 </li>
 <li>
 <span>Pagina {{curPage + 1}} van {{ numberOfPages() }}</span>
 </li>
 <li>
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
 ng-disabled="curPage >= questions.length/pageSize - 1"
 ng-click="curPage = curPage+1">Volgende pagina &gt;</button>
 </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance!

Thomas

Comment: input is not of the type "string/array", hence ".slice()" doesn't exist as function. put a console.log("input" + input); in there and check the developer console for its output.

Comment: It prints the following: input[object Object],[object Object],[object Object] (...). How can I do this for objects?

Comment: Can you include the HTML where this filter is used? (and any relevant data used at that time) (Plnk/fiddle would be even better)

Comment: I added this to my question! :)

Comment: "How can i do this for objects" -> use JSON.stringify(object) to serialize the object in JSON notation.

Comment: So my function would be: start = +start;
  JSON.stringify(input);
  return input.slice(start); ? Thanks in advance!

Comment: console.log("input: " + JSON.stringify(input) + "\r\n" + "start: " + start);

Comment: It does not fix my problem. I keep getting two times the error: 'undefined is not a function'. I added already the line: 'JSON.stringify(input)'. Without this line I'm getting the error three times. Thanks in advance for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check before slicing if the input is array

```
angular.module('app').filter('pagination', function(){
    return function(input, start)
    {
        start = +start;
        if(angular.isArray(input) && input.length > 0) {
             return input.slice(start);
        }
        //console.log(input);
        return input;
    };
});
```

you can use console.log to check if the input is not an array

Comment: Great, the error is gone! Bad that I couldn't find it myself.